# How to separate a word with "-" in ansible

Tags: ansible

Step1: I am fetching ec2 metadata details

```
---

- ec2_metadata_facts:
  register: instance_meta
- ec2_instance_info:
    instance_ids:
      - "{{ instance_meta.ansible_facts.ansible_ec2_instance_id }}"
    region: "{{ instance_meta.ansible_facts.ansible_ec2_placement_region }}"
  register: instance_info

- name: Gather and Save Instance Info
  set_fact:
      Application: "{{ instance_info.instances | map(attribute='tags.Application') | list | join('\n') }}"
      Component: "{{ instance_info.instances | map(attribute='tags.Component') | list | join('\n') }}"
      Namespace: "{{ instance_info.instances | map(attribute='tags.Namespace') | list | join('\n') }}"
      Environment: "{{ instance_info.instances | map(attribute='tags.Environment') | list | join('\n') }}"
```

Steps 2:

In vars/main.yml I have below code

```
license_key_name: "{{ Namespace }}"-"{{ Application }}"-"{{ Environment }}"
newrelic_license_keys: {
    'dth-tld-ops1': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'dth-fld-ops2': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'dth-glb-ops1': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'dth-plb-ops2': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'dth-leu-pro2': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
}
```

Step 3: In defaults/main.yml

```
nrinfragent_config:
  license_key: newrelic_license_keys[license_key_name]
```

Step 4:

In templates/file.j2

```
{# Print out all the configuration options #}
{{ nrinfragent_config | to_nice_yaml }}

{# For backward compatibility, the license key will be written if it is defined #}
{% if nrinfragent_license_key is defined %}
license_key: "{{ newrelic_license_keys[license_key_name] }}"
{% endif %}
```

Jinja template should fetch the correct license from vars/main.yml file. We have multiple AWS env each have separate new relic license.

ERROR:

```
license_key_name: "{{ Namespace }}"-"{{ Application }}"-"{{ Environment }}"
                                   ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:
    with_items:
      - {{ foo }}
Should be written as:
    with_items:
      - "{{ foo }}"
```

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps surround the entire expression in quotes `"{{ Namespace }}-{{ Application }}-{{ Environment }}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to surround the whole value with quotes, not each variable separately

license_key_name: "{{ Namespace }}-{{ Application }}-{{ Environment }}"